# Pymongo find in subcollections?

Tags: python, pymongo

```py
import pymongo

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["test"]
mycol = mydb["a_test"]
for doc in mycol.find({mycol['segmentos'[{'etiquetas'[{'categoria'}]}]]: "3"}):
        i += 1
print(i)
```

I receive the following error when I execute this program

```
for doc in mycol.find({mycol['segmentos'[{'etiquetas'[{'categoria'}]}]]: "3"}):
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I'm using bad the find function of pymongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would need to see your database structure to confirm, but you can filter on subdocuments by using dot notation e.g.

```
for doc in mycol.find({'segmentos.etiquetas.categoria': "3"}):
```